# How to create pretty url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url, pretty-urls

I have a link like `http://example.com/file.php?id=7gJKw2&d=78sfmnnsd8`

I want to make this above url as

```
http://example.com/file/7gJKw2/78sfmnnsd8
```

Here is what I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ file.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1
```

How can i add the value of `d` & make it good looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle the entire `a-zA-Z0-9_` pattern into a simple `\w`. As to the real question, just add the second part as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ file.php?id=$1&d=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^file/([\w.-]+)/?$ file.php?id=$1 [L]
```